# How do I calculate the difference between incidences?

Tags: heteroscedasticity

I'm making a study on the necessity of routine omentectomy in ovarian cancer patients.

The plan is to first find the incidence of occult metastases of the omentum in ovarian cancer patients, and afterwards I would like to compare my study's incidence to other published incidences...

In other words, I want to know if it is statistically different or not to the other published incidences.

What method should I use to calculate that?

Thank you v much.